# About Updating linux-headers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel

I did dist-upgrade on kali 2.0, after update when i tried to reboot it waited too long i thought it locked or something.

I manually turn off pc.

After restart it was working normally but when i try to install something manually(with make) then i realize my mistake.

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

That error showed up when i try to make,

After that i try to install linux-headers with that command,

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but i was getting another error. It was says like "There's no package". I dont remember exactly.

old uname -r

```
4.3.0-kali1-amd64
```

and i installed new headers,

```
4.4.0-kali1-amd64
```

Now there is 2 directory in /lib/modules/

```
4.3.0-kali1-amd64/ 4.4.0-kali1-amd64/
```

When i write uname -r it still show me old header(4.3.0-kali1-amd64)

I tried to `update-initframs -u` but didnt worked.
When i try to make it still say same error

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.3.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

How can i fix it ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably meet this problem that lack of linux headers when you install the VMware Tools.

In fact, there's new way to solve the issue in official Kali website: http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest.

As the tutorial says, if your version of VMware is after Sept 2015, you can use the following code to install it:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
reboot
```

Then, you may find you can use the VMware Tools and with the linux-headers updating.

Comment: I dont use Vmware but thanks anyway i solved a problem after couple of hours but i dont remember now.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Apologize that I assume you want to use VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my experience with this problem - using hardware not VM.

I installed Kali Linux from a live memory stick. Whilst installing I didn't have an internet connection.

This meant that my sources.list file was set to "Default Off-line Install Values". This meant that when installing I was limited to just the packages and data from the memory stick I Initially installed from.

To fix this, you need to change your sources.list (called switching branches):

Open terminal:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This opens the sources file

Now at the top of the file paste in the following two lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Press CTRL X then Press Y and Enter to save the file.

Now you can type the following commands to update Kali:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

And finally, you should now be able to...

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This is just my unique experience with this error stemming from an offline install.
I hope this helps someone else out there.

Reference - https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/